# Running command line commands from Thor executable

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, thor

In my executable Ruby file I have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'thor'

include Thor::Actions

class UI < Thor
  # def self.source_root
  #   File.dirname(__FILE__)
  # end

  desc "makecal", "Generates postscript calendar to your desktop"
  def makecal
    # puts `ls ~`
    puts run('ls ~')
    # puts run "pcalmakecal -B -b all -d Helvetica/8 -t Helvetica/16 -S #{Time.now.month} #{Time.now.year} > ~/Desktop/#{Time.now.month}-#{Time.now.year}"
  end
end

UI.start
```

In the terminal when I run the file as is I get an empty line as Thor's run command is returning a NilClass.

However, when I un-comment the puts `ls ~` and comment out Thor's run method I get an output of my home directory as expected.

I'm having trouble figuring out why I can't get Thor's run method to work like Ruby's ticks.

Any ideas where I may have went wrong?

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1):

I didn't put the include statement inside my class and that messed things up. The code should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'makecal'


class UI < Thor
  include Thor::Actions
  # def self.source_root
  #   File.dirname(__FILE__)
  # end
  #

  desc "makecal", "Generates postscript calendar to your desktop"
  def makecal
    # puts `ls ~`
    puts run('ls ~')
    # puts run "pcal -B -b all -d Helvetica/8 -t Helvetica/16 -S #{Time.now.month} #{Time.now.year} > ~/Desktop/#{Time.now.month}-#{Time.now.year}"
  end
end

UI.start
```

Comment: Can you just edit your initial post so that this is the code listing?

Comment: Heh, sadly this was my problem - a bit anti climatic. When I properly include Thor::Actions, run() behaves as I expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

Thor's documentation on this method is actually wrong and incomplete.  It documents that it returns the "contents of the command" (which I assume means the standard output), but it, by defualt, does nothing.

*But*, you can, apparently, use the `:capture` option to get what you want:

```
unless options[:pretend]
  config[:capture] ? `#{command}` : system("#{command}")
end
```

So, try doing

```
puts run("ls ~", :capture => true)
```

And see if that does it.

Comment: I noticed this too, but despite that it still seems to return the standard output no matter what I set the capture flag to. When I set capture to false, it prints an extra 'true' after each command I run after Thor's output and after the standard output. When I set it to true, it doesn't print the extra 'true'. Its almost like its always using the ticks instead of the system().